# How to select rows using three columns

Tags: database, r, dataframe

I have a data.frame in R. I want to select rows that have a specific value **in one** of three columns. I have a **large data.frame**, but what I need is like the example below:

```
seller<-c("Mary", "Bill", "Jeff", "Paty", "Paul", "Criss")
c1<-c(1,2,1,1,3,1)
c2<-c(1,1,1,1,2,1)
c3<-c(1,1,3,1,1,1)
data<-data.frame(seller, c1, c2, c3)

>data
       seller c1 c2 c3
   1   Mary  1  1  1
   2   Bill  2  1  1
   3   Jeff  1  1  3
   4   Paty  1  1  1
   5   Paul  3  2  1
   6   Cris  1  1  1
```

I want to select the rows that have values ​​equal and greater than 2, like this:

```
>data
       seller c1 c2 c3
   1   Bill  2  1  1
   2   Jeff  1  1  3
   3   Paul  3  2  1
```

**Thanks for the help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but you can use `rowSums` and `which` to subset, as in the following example:

```
data[which(rowSums(data[-1]) > ncol(data[-1])), ]
#   seller c1 c2 c3
# 2   Bill  2  1  1
# 3   Jeff  1  1  3
# 5   Paul  3  2  1
```

A more direct alternative is:

```
data[which(apply(data[-1], 1, function(x) any(x >= 2))), ]
```

I've used `data[-1]` to remove the names of the sellers (as they are character strings). Then, `apply` with margin `1` applies the specified function *by row* (margin `2` would do the same by column). The function is `any(x >= 2)`, which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each row; with `which`, we can subset the rows for which the return was `TRUE`.

Comment: This should work as well `data[rowSums(data[-1]) > ncol(data[-1]), ]`

Comment: `data[apply(data[,-1],1,function(x) any(x>=2)),]`